# Is it possible to make a web page that contains a Python script?

Tags: web-application, python

Is it possible to insert a Python script into a web page?
When a target (another PC, not mine) goes on this page it sees a normal picture and it thinks it is a normal joke. But before it sees this picture, a simple Python script (e.g. a TCP client sending the current time on the machine that surf the page) is executed.

How can I do this?

Comment: You may want to take a look at Flask.  It's a web development package built for Python.  It has a bit of a learning curve but if you're comfortable with Py then it should be a breeze. http://flask.pocoo.org/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python can be used to power websites through CGI, FastCGI, WSGI, or other server-side technologies. It cannot run directly in a browser, like JavaScript does, unless the user has a browser extension installed that specifically enables that (for instance, silverlight).

JavaScript has access to the current machine's clock time and can send that to a server.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot execute Python from a browser, browsers don't understand Python. What's more, the browser is deliberately restricted to what it can do on your local machine.

It might be possible to write a browser addin that allowed execution of Python. This is why it is important to think carefully about the addins/extensions you allow.

JavaScript is the language of the web and your browser *will* execute that. But still it is heavily restricted as to what it can do. All modern browsers run in a sandbox that attempts to ensure that any code that it might execute stays in a specific context. Normally, if you load a script from a web site, that script will only execute in that context and only have access to that site plus some local storage associated with that site. You could not, for example, create some JavaScript that deleted files on the C: drive and have that loaded from a server.